# google calender API in flutter

Tags: flutter, date, google-calendar-api

google calender API in flutter is not adding my event in the specific date that the user enters(i have a variable storing the input from the user)

It adds the event to today's date! So please If anyone can

```
Event event =
                                        Event(); // Create object of event
                                    event.summary = _apptNameController
                                        .text; //Setting summary of object (name of event)


                                

                                    EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime();
                                    // start.date = date; //setting start time
                                    start.dateTime = startTime;
                                    start.timeZone = DateTime.now()
                                        .timeZoneName; //local timezone
                                    event.start = start;

                                    EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime();
                                    // end.date = date; //setting end time
                                    end.timeZone = DateTime.now()
                                        .timeZoneName; //local timezone
                                    end.dateTime = endTime;
                                    event.end = end;

                                    insertEvent(event);
```

review my code and tell what to add or what to edit.

Comment: Can You be more clear and certain and please make your question better.

Comment: I think my question is very clear, anyways I already find the solution Thank you!

Comment: so answer your question so that anyone else is getting this error than they will get help so answer your question.

Comment: end.timeZone = DateTime.now().timeZoneName;  <-- remove that